# Trying to unset a session variable passed by reference to a class property

Tags: php, session-variables

Is it possible to pass a session variable to a class property by reference so that if you then unset the class property it will also unset the session variable? I thought that the following would work but the session is not being unset.

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Foo =& $_SESSION['bar'];
        $this->Foo = 123;
        unset($this->Foo);
        echo $_SESSION['bar'];
    }
}

new SomeClass; // Outputs "123"
```

Answer (score 2):

No, unsetting a reference in PHP simply removes the alternate handle that allowed you to refer to the original value -- it does not affect the original value itself.

There is no immediate workaround available, in this case you would have to keep `$_SESSION` and `'bar'` in separate variables and bring them together when the time comes to do what you need.